# Auto-detect GPU

Tags: winapi, gpu

I need detect GPU (videocard) and set settings of the app, appropriate to GPU performance.
I'm able to make a list with settings for each GPU model, but I don't understand how to easily detect model of GPU installed in PC.

What is the best way to solve this task? Does any way to do this that is not dependent on installed driver/some software?

Comment: Since new GPUs are released frequently, I wouldn't suggest maintaining a mapping like that.  Why not measure FPS of for example your menu screen, and use that to decide what settings to recommend?

Comment: It's not a videogame. I launch a lib from my app that uses GPU for computations.

Comment: So have an auto detect routine that runs some kernels and tests the speed.

Answer (score 0):

The above comment by Ben Voigt summarizes it: **Simply don't do it**.

See if the minimum version of your favorite compute API (OpenCL or whatever) is supported, and if the required extensions are present, compile some kernels, and see if that produces errors. Run the kernels and benchmark them. Ask the API how much local/global memory you have available, what warp sizes it supports, and so on.

If you really insist on detecting the GPU model, prepare for trouble. There are two ways of doing this, one is parsing the graphic card's advertised human readable name, this is asking for trouble right away (since many cards that are hugely different will advertise the same human-readable name, and some model names even *lie* about their architecture generation!).
The other, *slightly* better way is finding the vendor/model ID combination and looking that one up. This works somewhat better but it is equally painful and error-prone.

You can parse these vendor and model IDs from the "key" string inside the structure that you get when you call `EnumDisplayDevices`. Which, if I remember correctly, Microsoft calls "reserved", in other words it's kind of unsupported/undocumented.

Finding out the vendor is still *relatively* easy. A vendor ID of `0x10DE` is nVidia, and `0x1002` is AMD/ATI. `0x163C` is Intel. However, sometimes, very rarely, a cheapish OEM will advertise its own ID instead.

Then you have the kind of meaningless model number (it's not like bigger numbers are better, or some other obvious rule!), which you need to look up somewhere. nVidia and AMD publish these officially [[1]](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/device-id-list) [[2]](http://developer.amd.com/resources/hardware-drivers/ati-catalyst-pc-vendor-id-1002-li/), although they are not necessarily always up-to-date. There was a time when nVidia's list lacked the most recent models for almost one year (though the list I just downloaded seems to be complete). I'm not aware of other manufacturers, including Intel, doing this consistently.
Spending some time on Google will lead you to sites like [this one](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=606), which are not "official" but may allow you to figure out most stuff anyway... in a painstalking manner.

And then, you know the model, and you have gained pretty much nothing. You still need to translate this to "good enough for what I want" or "not good enough".
Which you could have found out simply by compiling your kernels and seeing that no error is reported, and running them.

And what do you do in 6 months when 3 new GPU models are released *after your application which obviously cannot know these has already shipped*? How do you treat these?